# SSRS Report value

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Working in SSRS I have columns of values, totals for the month on various parts. I want to be able to show graphically next to each one if the cost went up, down or stayed the same. For for example if, month 2 = month 3, it would show an equal embedded icon, etc. I have the icons in my report and I have an expression but its not working correctly for the column, could someone give me some insight?

Thanks

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!Expr1.Value, "MONTH2") < Sum(Fields!Expr1.Value, "MONTH3"), "up", 
    IIF(Sum(Fields!Expr1.Value, "MONTH2") > Sum(Fields!Expr1.Value, "MONTH3"), 
    "down", "equal"))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data set that you are using to get these? Chris Latta's answer expects that each row in your screenshot above is equivalent to a row returned by your query.

Comment: Yes, if you could show us your query that is used to get the data that is displayed above that will help us understand the data better and give a more accurate answer. Also, is it being displayed in a table or matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SUM expression as you are using it is for summing an entire dataset. For example:

```
SUM(Fields!Expr1.Value, "MONTH2")
```

sums the value of the `Expr` field over the entire dataset `MONTH2`

What you seem to be after is comparing field values within a row. Something like this:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!MONTH2.Value) < Sum(Fields!MONTH3.Value), "up", 
    IIF(Sum(Fields!MONTH2.Value) > Sum(Fields!MONTH3.Value), 
    "down", "equal"))
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will give it a try in the morning here.

Comment: Im getting an error: Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current data set scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified data set scope.